# Plugin de Push Notification para Phonegap

Tags: apache-cordova

Olá,
Alguém com experiência de uso com plugins do Phonegap para aplicar Push Notification?
O ideal seria um plugin que funcionasse com o Build do Phonegap

Qualquer ajuda agradeço

Comment: "Qualquer ajuda" sobre o que? Qual é a sua dúvida específica? O que vc tentou? Qual erro deu, em qual plugin? Não há nada de claro nessa sua pergunta. Por favor, edite-a e deixe a sua dúvida mais clara e objetiva, caso contrário ninguém conseguirá te ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, nos meus projetos utilizando Phonegap, venho usando [este aqui](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push).

Até então não tive nenhum problema com ele. Comunidade ativa no seu desenvolvimento e aprimoramento.

[]'s

Comment: Valeu! Me parece muito bom mesmo
Abs!